# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in JUnit tests

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric

This one is kind of a shot in the dark. I'm getting the following error occasionally when running my robolectric unit test suite:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
  at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)
  at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getOverlayedThemeValue(ShadowResources.java:294)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.findAttributeValue(ShadowResources.java:284)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:187)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:51)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:489)
  at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
  at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:416)
  at android.view.View.__constructor__(View.java:3317)
  at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$3.run(ReflectionHelpers.java:144)
  at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:241)
  at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:138)
  at org.robolectric.internal.Shadow.invokeConstructor(Shadow.java:73)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.__constructor__(ShadowView.java:109)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java)
  at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu.createLabels(FloatingActionsMenu.java:461)
  at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu.onFinishInflate(FloatingActionsMenu.java:447)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:763)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
  at com.myapp.app.view.activity.MainActivityActivity.onCreate(MainActivityActivity.java:75)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
  at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$3.run(ReflectionHelpers.java:144)
  at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:241)
  at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:138)
  at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:114)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:309)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:47)
  at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:110)
  at com.myapp.app.BaseActivityRobolectricTest.startActivity(BaseActivityRobolectricTest.java:58)
  at com.myapp.app.BaseActivityRobolectricTest.startActivity(BaseActivityRobolectricTest.java:34)
  at com.myapp.app.view.activity.MainActivityActivityTest.setupActivity(MainActivityActivityTest.java:52)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
  at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
  at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:167)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
  at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
  at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm having a horrible time making light of this stacktrace and what could be going on. Has anybody run into this and found a solution?

I found one issue on Robolectric's github that suggests doing a `clean` before executing the tests. While it seems to minimize the number of times this test fails, it's still failing on occasion.

MainActivityActivity.java:75 is         `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

The test:

```
@Before
public void setupActivity() {
    setupAuthObjectGraphWithFakeData();
    startActivity(RequestReviewsActivity.class, new ParentModule(), null);
}

protected void startActivity(Class<T> activityClass, Object module, Intent intent) {
    mActivityController = buildActivity(activityClass);

    if(intent != null) {
        mActivityController.withIntent(intent);
    }

    mActivity = mActivityController.get();

    List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.addAll(mActivity.getModules());
    modules.add(module);

    ObjectGraph objectGraph;
    if(mActivity instanceof AuthedActivity) {
        objectGraph = BaseApplication.getInstance().getAuthObjectGraph().plus(modules.toArray());
    } else {
        objectGraph = BaseApplication.getInstance().getAppObjectGraph().plus(modules.toArray());
    }
    mActivity.setObjectGraph(objectGraph);

    mActivityController.create(mBundle).start().resume();
}

@Test
public void testViewsAreAvailable() {
    assertThat(getActivity().mToolbar).isNotNull();
    assertThat(getActivity().mContent).isNotNull();
    assertThat(getActivity().mContentShadow).isNotNull();
    assertThat(getActivity().mRequestRootFab).isNotNull();
    assertThat(getActivity().mRequestReviewsList).isNotNull();
    assertThat(getActivity().mRequestReviewsMainContent).isNotNull();
}
```

**Update:**

This issue goes away when not running Activity specific unit tests (similar to the following). For the time being I've had to comment out these tests.

I'm generally following the Robolectric approach found here - http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/ with some updates (since that article is a bit old).

I'm executing the tests with a `./gradlew test`

Comment: This is very intriguing :) How are you running tests? Is it in parallel by any chance?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu to my knowledge I'm not. I'm following the general approach found here: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/. Executing with `./gradlew test`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using something like Fabric or Crashlytics, make sure to disable it in your Robolectric tests. *We've* been running into a very similar issue and through some local debugging, we were able to find the thread that was causing the issue. When Fabric initializes, it starts a background thread which accesses some resources. My thought is that this is primarily a bug with Robolectric in that it doesn't handle resource loading in a thread safe manner but there really is no need for Crashlytics in a unit testing environment so this is a quick fix.

Typically, a user will initialize Fabric or Crashlytics in their `Application` class. Robolectric allows you to make a "Test" `Application` class by prefixing your current class with the word "Test". In your original `Application` class, make a separate method for initializing the crash reporting system. In your `TestApplication`, override that method and make sure it is empty so Fabric is not initialized in your tests. For example:

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupCrashReporting();
    }

    protected void setupCrashReporting() {
        CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();

        Crashlytics crashlytics = new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(core)
                .build();

        Fabric.with(this, crashlytics);
    }
}
```

TestApp.java

```
public class TestApp extends App {
    @Override
    protected void setupCrashReporting() {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

This helped resolve the issue in *our* apps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution but my concern is in this way Crashlytics is not able to catch crashes in Debug mode that if you are in a big organization with many testers that use Debug version then you are in problem otherwise (if they use release version for testing) then this is awesome idea.

Comment: @Hesam if you want it to work in debug builds, then just remove the `.disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)` line and then it will be enabled for all builds (except test builds as long as you have the `TestApp` class present)

Comment: Thanks man, I had few errors from Crashlytics that your solution fixed that, however I still have `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` issue that I'm not sure it is Robolectric issue or build flavor issue it is :( omg

Comment: @plackemacher, I had Analytics under my `onCreate()` that I removed it based on your suggestion. Now my problem is my debug test cases passes while release test cases fail :( I have two flavors both `test_X_DebugUnitTest` and `text_Y_DebugUnitTest` passes while `test_X_ReleaseUnitTest` and `text_Y_ReleaseUnitTest` fails :( Do you have any idea regard this? thanks for the help man.

Comment: @plackemacher bro, can you have a look at my question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/33661731/513413. Thanks.

Comment: Great solution! I had plenty of errors due to NPE and IllegalStateExceptions which were solved by using a custom Application class for my tests (in which Crashlytics is not started). Thanks!